# Greasemonkey Script and Function Scope

Tags: javascript, firefox, scope, greasemonkey

Here is my script code:

```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name          test 
    // @description   test
    // @include       http://*
    // @copyright     Bruno Tyndall
    // ==/UserScript==

    var main = function() {
        var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var t = document.createElement('div');
        t.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color:white;">Hello World</a>';
        t.style.position = 'absolute';
        t.style.zIndex = 1000;
        t.style.bottom = '5px';
        t.style.right = '5px';
        t.firstChild.setAttribute('onclick', 'test();');
        b.appendChild(t);

    }

    var test = function() {
        alert("Hello World");
    }
    main();
```

The only issue I have is when Hello World is clicked the page cannot find the test() function. Please tell me I don't have to solve it by innerHTML'ing the function onto the page like [this](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/40443). Is there another way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Greasemonkey executes the script in a sandbox - the page doesn't have access to it for security reasons. All acceses to dom and window are via wrappers.

If you want to access the unsecured objects you can use `wrappedJSObject` property.

For your case you can use `unsafeWindow` (or `window.wrappedJSObject`):

```
unsafeWindow.test = function() { ....
```

There are some security issues with this, see: http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow

Also, greasemonkey executes the script after the DOMContentLoaded (when the dom is ready) event so you don't need that onload nonsense.

Also, you can't use attributes to set event listeners, or properties for that matter - you must use dom api for that. Eg:

```
t.firstChild.addEventListener('click', test, false);
```

or:

```
t.firstChild.addEventListener('click', function(event){ blabla }, false);
```

Comment: +1. Thanks. I would appreciate your thoughts on where I am stuck now. I posted it over on http://userscripts.org/topics/21770 I can't get the inline anon function to work either.

Comment: I should add... I get zero help from the Error Console as far as to what is going wrong.

Comment: In case anybody missed that I was using onclick instead of click.

Answer (score 2):

iirc, greasemonkey runs within it's own scope, so test will not be in the global namespace.

Instead of poluting the global though, why not create your anchor element through DOM manipulation? That will return you a refernece which you can bind an anonymous function (or the greasemonkey scoped test).

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? How would you do it if you want to keep the function "non-anonymous" (scoped in Greasemonkey). What do you mean by bind?

Comment: I'm creating the anchor through DOM manipulation now. But I don't see how to "bind" the function correctly.

Comment: I satrted answering this and then saw you got there already :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the function test to the window object

```
window.test = function ...
```

**Edit**

Also, it's a good idea to run your code from a 'load' event handler instead of just by calling it at the end of your scripts. e.g.:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
 // Your main() here
}, false);
```

Comment: The window.test = function ... did not work for me. still gave me the test not defined error.

Comment: Are you calling window.test() in main?

Comment: @AssafLavie I'm stuck in a similar (but not surly identical) problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720005/vanilla-javascript-code-works-in-console-but-not-from-a-greasemonkey-script?noredirect=1#comment86466847_49720005). Care to have a look? Thanks anyway.