# Vanilla JavaScript code works in console but not from a (greasemonkey) script

Tags: javascript, debugging, dom, console, href

I use Windows10 home with latest Firefox and Greasemonkey.

I created an account in [livedns.co.il](https://domains.livedns.co.il), which is an Israeli domain register. I then logged in.

After logging in to the **personal overview area**, I tried to move myself to the **domains management area**, via this code:

```
window.location.href = "https://domains.livedns.co.il/DomainsList.aspx";
```

It worked in console but not from a greasemonkey script.

I thought I might need `setTimeout()` in the script:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
        window.location.href = "https://domains.livedns.co.il/DomainsList.aspx";
}, 1000);
```

but this code also worked only in console.

### Steps to reproduce

After creating an account and logging in, this is the original pattern I used:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        livednsAutoLogin
// @include     https://domains.livedns.co.il/Default.aspx
// ==/UserScript==

console.log(window.location.href); // This fails in Greasemonkey if the code below exists; If I'll delete all code below, it will succeed in Greasemonkey;

document.querySelector("#ctl00_TopLoginBox1_txtUname").value = "myUsername";
document.querySelector("#ctl00_TopLoginBox1_txtPassword").value = "myPassword";
document.querySelector("#ctl00_TopLoginBox1_btnLogin > .FltRt").click();

setTimeout(()=>{
        window.location.href = "https://domains.livedns.co.il/DomainsList.aspx";
}, 250);
```

Just change username and password, then test.

### My question

What makes a vanilla JavaScript code to work in console but not from a (greasemonkey) script? In particular, why does the changing of href of location of the document works only in console but not in a Greasemonkey script?

I don't know how to debug in such a case because I don't see an error in console when I run the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug Greasemonkey script with the Firebug extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490062/how-to-debug-greasemonkey-script-with-the-firebug-extension)

Answer (score 1):

I had a logical mistake when running the code from the wrong url (I should have ensured that I'm in `https://domains.livedns.co.il/Main.aspx` to successfully run the code. I fixed that by using if-then conditionals (I'll find out if I'm having any significant security threat using this way).

Note how I changed the `@include` and had richer usage of URLs.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        livednsAutoLogin
// @include     *livedns.co.il/*
// ==/UserScript==

if ( document.location.href == "https://domains.livedns.co.il/" ) {
    document.querySelector("#ctl00_TopLoginBox1_txtUname").value = "myEmail";
  document.querySelector("#ctl00_TopLoginBox1_txtPassword").value = "myPassword";
  document.querySelector("#ctl00_TopLoginBox1_btnLogin > .FltRt").click();
}

if ( document.location.href == "https://domains.livedns.co.il/Main.aspx" ) {
    console.log(window.location.href);
  document.location.href = "https://domains.livedns.co.il/DomainsList.aspx"  
}
```